# Understanding d3.js update with button click instead of page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to figure out, how to update a d3.js chart. After reading through examples,- very well explained here: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch09.html#_ordinal_scales_explained - I think that I do understand the principles, but not in depth yet.

The following code plots Jim's bubble chart after page refresh and click on div with event handler - code simplified:

```
jQuery(function($) {

root.plotData = function(selector, data, plot) {
return d3.select(selector).datum(data.slice(start=0,stop=10)).call(plot);
};

plot = Bubbles();

display = function(data) {
return plotData("#vis", data, plot);
};

return d3.csv(url, display);
});
```

Now I would like to update the chart:

```
$("#some_id").on("click",function(){

updateLabels = function() {


root.plotData = function(selector, data, plot) {
return d3.select(selector).datum(data.slice(start=10,stop=20)).call(plot);
};

plot = Bubbles();

display = function(data) {
return plotData("#vis", data, plot);
};

return d3.csv(url, display);
});

});
});
```

However, the display function is not called from my button unless I refresh the page first. I am a bit confused about what the issue might be.
Why does the first click render, but the second does not ?

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle

Comment: I simplified the code; am not sure about how to put up the fiddle; the entire code, or just what I have here ?

Comment: you are on the right track. You need to put your chart creation in a function like you have but as you said your data only changes when you refresh the page. Change it so the data updates on button click then in turn run the chart update function

Comment: thisOneGuy - thank you. Maybe you can help me through the logic of this:

after a page refresh my button click works and the graphic  is drawn. A  click another button seems to invoke the EventHandler, but the graphic is not redrawn. Only after a page refresh that second button would work as expected.
Is that to be expected ?  Is something else required to redraw the graphic ? Why is the 2nd btn click not triggering the redraw of the graphic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
function clicked_eventHandler() {

// insert here  code chart rendering based on Jim's force directed layout bubble charts

jQuery(function($) {

// removing all children from element id="vis"
var svg = d3.select("#vis");
svg.selectAll("*").remove();


// running the display function
the new dataset is created by slicing the data setting two variables
start and stop ( here for test purposes set to 0, 10 ). This allows to slice rows 
out of a long csv file.


root.plotData = function(selector, data, plot) {
return    d3.select(selector).datum(data.slice(start=0,stop=10)).call(plot);
};

plot = Bubbles();

display = function(data) {
return plotData("#vis", data, plot);
};

return d3.csv(url, display);
});

};
```

Realizing that I needed a page refresh to clear the id="vis", I decided to start the function with selecting id="vis" and removing all children. Now  the btn click event ( dynamically created btns with each different parameters in the function ) works on each btn and not only on page refresh. Suggestions to improve my solution are certainly welcome.